# Average-case retrieval time

Tags: hash, average-case

The book CLRS claims these statements before introducing the topic of universal hashing:

If a malicious adversary chooses the keys to be hashed by some fixed hash function,
then the adversary can choose n keys that all hash to the same slot, yielding an average retrieval time of $\Theta(n)$. Any fixed hash function is vulnerable to such terrible worst-case behavior.

I think by retrieval it means searching. So why is it $\Theta(n)$? Clearly, the worst-case is $O(n)$ but why is the average-case the same? Shouldn't it be $O(1)$ rather than $\Theta(n)$? Maybe we should use the definition of average-case time complexity here or maybe it's just a mistake in the book. Maybe.

Comment: It seems that for a fixed hash function and for a fixed set of keys, they are taking the average search time of these keys. Suppose key $i$ has a search time $t_i$. Then, the average search time is $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} t_i/n$. In that case, the average search time is $\Theta(n)$ in the worst case: when all keys are mapped to the same slot.